# Data Rowfilter in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, I am using dataview in rowfilter i am using like opertor but it is giving error :

```
dv.RowFilter = "FirstName like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'"; 
error is : could not find the column [Firstname]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "could not find the column" is telling you that no column by the name "Firstname" exists in your DataView. Check your DataView and add the column.

Alternatively, post some code that shows how you populate your DataView, so that we can better assist you.